# xlsx to csv without formulas in python, openpyxl or win32com

Tags: python

Is there way i can save an xlsx as csv and also i will need to remove formulas.

Edit-->My excel column B "price" is updated via webservice addin every 10 secs (stock prices).somehow if how if i save file using openpyxl using the option dataonly=true, i am not getting the most recent price instead it is gettiing some old values (getting the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet)

Orginal File

```
            A             B
           StockId     Price
            13i         16.1353
            14i         15.4252   --> formuala = RTD(A3,"Last", "HSC","xxx")
```

New File Created using opepyxl (data only true)-formula removed but price is not most recent

```
              A            B
             StockId     Price
             13i         15.1353
             14i         15.3252
```

Instead of using openpyxl, if i use win32 com to read the excel file, out file is still keeping the formula. is there anyway i can remove the formula.

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Code\test.xlsx")
ws = xl.ActiveSheet
wb.SaveAs(r"C:\Code\test.csv")
wb.Close()
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: "getting the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet"... And what other values can be stored in the file?

Comment: First, whenever you save an Excel worksheet into csv, formulas are removed and their values are retained. Second, the resulting csv would store values in the last saved instance of Excel file. As Juan points out, what did you want it to do? Please clarify for readers.

Answer (score 0):

`data_only=True` applies only to reading files with openpyxl: the option is meaningless for writing files.